# Multiple writes to SQLite from Perl

Tags: perl, sqlite

Assume I have two Perl scripts connected to the same SQLite database. If one of the scripts is writing to the database, and the other one also tries to write to the database, will the second script connection get disconnected? or will its input get stored in some SQLite cache and SQLite will eventually commit the writes after the writes from the first script are done?

I don't want my second script connection die just because SQLIte locks the db because of the writes from the first script. Is this what would happen if both scripts write to the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. SQLite doesn't allow concurrent writes.

From [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html):

> To write to a database, a process must first acquire a SHARED lock as
>   described above (possibly rolling back incomplete changes if there is
>   a hot journal). After a SHARED lock is obtained, a RESERVED lock must
>   be acquired.
>
> A RESERVED lock means that the process is planning on writing to the
>   database file at some point in the future but that it is currently
>   just reading from the file. Only a single RESERVED lock may be active
>   at one time, though multiple SHARED locks can coexist with a single
>   RESERVED lock. RESERVED differs from PENDING in that new SHARED locks
>   can be acquired while there is a RESERVED lock.

Comment: If your application isn't under a heavy load, simply wrapping the write in a `try/catch` and retrying several times should fix all the problems.

Comment: I guess this comment is directed at the question. In any case I would rather synchronize the accesses.